# Клиент-серверное приложение android

Tags: java, android

Нужно создать клиент серверное приложение, которое выводит список файлов по категориям. Например на сервере лежат папки a, b и c с различными файлами. А в приложении выводится список папок и после выбора папки список файлов с их описанием и возможностью скачать нужный файл.
Где начать копать и есть ли туториалы, где реализуется подобный функционал?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Клиент-серверное приложение андроид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168523/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочешь сделать простое приложение без графичесского интерфейса, в консоли, то тебе нужно гуглить на тематику:

1. List Files in a Directory in Java
   https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-directory-files
2. Что такое сокет
   https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/654-klassih-socket-i-serversocket-ili-allo-server-tih-menja-slihshishjh
3. Работа с файлами и каталогами
   https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.11.php

Если нужно полнофункциональное приложение.
Чтобы написать такое приложение нужно знать как совершать запросы CRUD(create,read,update,delete). Нужно знать что такое клиент-серверное приложение, можешь попробывать написать простенькое клиент-серверное приложение для начала, чтобы понять как клиент связывается с сервером. Тебе нужно знать какой либо GUI(graphic user interface) для Андроид чтобы иметь возможность выбрать папку с помощью графического интерфейса, а не через консоль. Можно использовать много различных фреймворков для отображения файлов или различных папок, и также можно использовать много различных фрейморков для скачивания файлов, многое зависит от выбора фреймворков для приложения. Я бы для мобильного приложения выбрал бы такой стек технологий, то есть именно этот стек тебе нужно знать:

Flutter(для графичесского интерфейса)

Socket(Для связи с сервером)

Sqlite(база данных)

Но на самом деле, фреймворков существует очень много и тебе самому надо определиться какой тебе нужен. Тебе нужно для начала Выбрать фреймворк для графичесского интерфейса, Знать как связать сервер и клиент, и выбрать базу данных, как минимум.